# Using ajax to refresh a div in a for each loop, wrong result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I've been struggling with this for a while, i have a div and a form in a for each loop and on submitting one of the forms in the loop, the content of its div is updated in the database and refreshed ("div only"). This is done using JavaScript and Ajax. My update query works fine, JavaScript handles the form and Ajax refreshes only the div in the page. My **problem** is, upon refreshing all the contents in the  loop are put into one div but instead i want  one content to one div as many times the loop is run, to better understand my problem please refer to the image below:
**Before:**
[image: before"]

**After first like button is clicked:**

[image: after]

**This is the result i expect to see:**

[image]

**info.php**

```
<html>
<head>
 .......
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ajaxform').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // catch the form's submit event
  $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
  data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
  type: "POST", // POST
  dataType:'html',
  url: "test.php", // the file to call
  cache: false, 
  success: function(response) { // on success..
  $('.ld').html(response);

    }
      });
   return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
   });
       }); 
   </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
 <?php
  ...........
  foreach($stmt as $obj){
     $username = $obj['user_name'];
      $comment = $obj['comment'];
      $id = $obj['id'];
  $userimage = $obj['user_image'];
  $row ++;
  $likes = $obj['like1'];
  $dislikes = $obj['dislike'];
  echo '<div class="txt">';
  echo '<div class="comment-container">';
  echo '<div class="comment-item">';
    echo '<div class="comment-avatar">';
      echo '<img src="user/user_images/'.$userimage.'" alt="avatar">';
    echo '</div>';
     echo '<div class="comment-post">';
      echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$username.'&nbsp&nbspsaid....  
     </span>';
      echo '<p style="margin-left:-11px;">'.$comment.'</p>';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="'.$id.'">';
      echo '<form action="" method="post" class="ajaxform"   
           enctype="multipart/form-data">';//form to submit

       echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkcv[]" value="'.$id.'">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="'.$type_id.'">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="stk" value="'.$likes.'">';
      echo '<input type="image" src="images/like.png" id="lksub" width="15"
          value="som" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;margin-
             right:290px;"/><div class="ld">'.$likes.'</div>';//div to refresh

      echo '</form>';
      echo '<form action="" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkd_id" value="'.$id.'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="dislike" value="">';
        echo ' <input type= "image" id="submit" src="images/dislike.png" 
              width="15" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;
              margin-top:-14px;margin-right:230px;"/>
             <div class="ldks">'.$dislikes.'</div>';
             echo '</form>';
            echo '<span class="SendCopy">Reply</span> ';
            echo '<div class="users">';
           echo '<form action="" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-
                  data">';
           echo '<textarea rows="4"  name="replycomment" style="float:right;
                  resize: none;margin-top:5px;" cols="50" >';
            echo '</textarea>';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="'.$id.'">';
         echo '<input type="submit" name="reply" id="submit" class="post-
                 button" value="Send" />';
         echo '</form>';

          echo '</div>';

         echo '</div>';

          echo '</div>';  

         echo '</div>'; 
        echo '</div>';

          ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Anonmy");


if( isset( $_POST['lkcv'] ) && is_array( $_POST['lkcv'] ) )
 {

$idArray = array();

foreach( $_POST['lkcv'] as $value )
{
    $idArray[] = intval( $value );
}

$mysqli->query( "UPDATE comment SET like1 = like1 + 1 WHERE id IN (".implode(
 ',', $idArray ).")" );


 }


  ?>
 <?php 

   $host   = 'localhost';
   $dbname = 'dbname';
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Anonmy', $username,
   $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   $type_id = $_POST['pid'];
   $like = $_POST['stk'];
   $target_no = 3;
   echo '<div class="wrap">';

   // retrive comments with post id
   $stmt = $conn->prepare(
    "SELECT *
     FROM comment
      WHERE post_id = :pid
      ");

      $stmt->bindParam(":pid", $type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);


      $stmt->execute();


     foreach($stmt as $obj){
     $username = $obj['user_name'];
      $comment = $obj['comment'];
      $id = $obj['id'];
      $userimage = $obj['user_image'];
      $likes = $obj['like1'];
      $dislikes = $obj['dislike'];

      echo '<div class="">'.$likes.'</div>';


         }

            ?>
      </body>
      </html>
```

How can i modify my code to achieve the result in image 3.

**test.php[updated]**

```
   $host   = 'localhost';
   $dbname = 'dbname';
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Anonmy', $username,
   $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   $type_id = $_POST['pid'];
   $like = $_POST['stk'];
   $target_no = 3;
   echo '<div class="wrap">';

   // retrive comments with post id
   $stmt = $conn->prepare(
    "SELECT *
     FROM comment
      WHERE post_id = :pid
      ");

      $stmt->bindParam(":pid", $type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);


      $stmt->execute();

//updated
$result = array();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
$result[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'likes' => $row['like1'], 'dislikes' => 
$row['dislike']);
  }
echo json_encode($result);
    ?>
```

**info.php[updated]**

```
<html>
<head>
 .......
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ajaxform').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // catch the form's submit event
   //updated
  $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
type: "POST", // POST
dataType:'json',
url: "test.php", // the file to call
cache: false, // Not needed for POST
success: function(response) { // on success..
    $.each(response, function(i, el) {
        var comment_post = $("#comment-post-" + el.id);
        comment_post.find(".ld").text(el.likes);
        comment_post.find(".ldks").text(el.dislikes);
    });
      }
        });
   return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
   });
       }); 
   </script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <?php
  ...........
  foreach($stmt as $obj){
     $username = $obj['user_name'];
      $comment = $obj['comment'];
      $id = $obj['id'];
  $userimage = $obj['user_image'];
  $row ++;
  $likes = $obj['like1'];
  $dislikes = $obj['dislike'];
  echo '<div class="txt">';
  echo '<div class="comment-container">';
  echo '<div class="comment-item">';
    echo '<div class="comment-avatar">';
      echo '<img src="user/user_images/'.$userimage.'" alt="avatar">';
    echo '</div>';
     echo '<div class="comment-post" id="comment-post-' . $id .'">';//updated
      echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$username.'&nbsp&nbspsaid....  
     </span>';
      echo '<p style="margin-left:-11px;">'.$comment.'</p>';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="'.$id.'">';
      echo '<form action="" method="post" class="ajaxform"   
           enctype="multipart/form-data">';//form to submit

       echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkcv[]" value="'.$id.'">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="'.$type_id.'">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="stk" value="'.$likes.'">';
      echo '<input type="image" src="images/like.png" id="lksub" width="15"
          value="som" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;margin-
             right:290px;"/><div class="ld">'.$likes.'</div>';//div to refresh

      echo '</form>';
      echo '<form action="" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkd_id" value="'.$id.'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="dislike" value="">';
        echo ' <input type= "image" id="submit" src="images/dislike.png" 
              width="15" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;
              margin-top:-14px;margin-right:230px;"/>
             <div class="ldks">'.$dislikes.'</div>';
             echo '</form>';
            echo '<span class="SendCopy">Reply</span> ';
            echo '<div class="users">';
           echo '<form action="" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-
                  data">';
           echo '<textarea rows="4"  name="replycomment" style="float:right;
                  resize: none;margin-top:5px;" cols="50" >';
            echo '</textarea>';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="'.$id.'">';
         echo '<input type="submit" name="reply" id="submit" class="post-
                 button" value="Send" />';
         echo '</form>';

          echo '</div>';

         echo '</div>';

          echo '</div>';  

         echo '</div>'; 
        echo '</div>';

          ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

**test.php[ajax response]**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2
/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1
/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".users").hide(); 
$(".SendCopy").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".users").slideToggle("slow");                              
});                        
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
 [{"id":"2","likes":"196","dislikes":"0"},   
  {"id":"5","likes":"80","dislikes":"0"}, 
  {"id":"6","likes":"45","dislikes":"0"},
  {"id":"7","likes":"31","dislikes":"0"}]  
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `$(".ld").html(response)` puts the response in **all** the `class="ld"` DIVs, not just the one they liked. You should return JSON that contains an array of all the IDs and likes, so you can update each one appropriately.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks. This is my first attempt at ajax and javascript, please could you give me an example of how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the HTML so that the post ID is included in the the ID of the DIV containing the like/dislike data.

```
echo '<div class="comment-post" id="comment-post-' . $id .'">';
```

Change `test.php` so it returns JSON instead of HTML:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $result[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'likes' => $row['like1'], 'dislikes' => $row['dislike']);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Remove all other code in `test.php` that produces output, like this line:

```
echo '<div class="wrap">';
```

The only output should be the JSON.

Then in the AJAX call, extract the JSON data and update each corresponding element with its likes and dislikes.

```
 $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    type: "POST", // POST
    dataType:'json',
    url: "test.php", // the file to call
    cache: false, // Not needed for POST
    success: function(response) { // on success..
        $.each(response, function(i, el) {
            var comment_post = $("#comment-post-" + el.id);
            comment_post.find(".ld").text(el.likes);
            comment_post.find(".ldks").text(el.dislikes);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time to do this, please could you check my updated code above to confirm that i have modified the code correctly as you specified?

Comment: Don't remove the original, broken code from the question. Future readers of the question need to see what the original problem was. If you want to show the new code, add it as an update at the end, not in place of the original.

Comment: If the new code does the right thing, you've probably modified it correctly.

Comment: as you suggested i have added an updated version of the code underneath the broken version. With the update, nothing happens when the like button is clicked(but after refreshing manually i can see the update). can you have a look at the updated version. Thanks

Comment: Remove `echo '<div class="wrap">';` from test.php

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? If you look in the Response section of the Network tab, do you see the JSON in the response?

Comment: i dont seem to be able to find an ajax response tab

Comment: You go to the console, you switch to the Network tab, you select the `test.php` URL. It should have sub-tabs named Headers, Previous, Response, Cookies, Timing (that's in Chrome, it might be slightly different in other browsers).

Comment: i've added the ajax response to the question.

Comment: I said in my answer that you have to remove ALL the output from `test.php` except the `echo json_encode($result);` line. Why do you still have all that HTML?

Comment: i've taken out all html in test.php, the response is `[{"id":"2","likes":"225","dislikes":"0"},{"id":"5","likes":"80","dislikes":"0"},{"id":"6","likes":"45","dislikes":"0"},{"id":"7","likes":"31","dislikes":"0"}]` the div doesn't refresh

Comment: I've removed all html in test.php, but the div wont refresh. Any suggestions?

Comment: never mind, i found my mistake. works perfectly :) thanks